# MongoDB syncing without having one primary?

Tags: mongodb, load-balancing

I have a setup that I haven't been able to find a solution for.  I'm setting up a load balancing solution between 2 different servers.  I would like each of these servers to have a local mongod instance so I don't increase load times by having one script connect to a remote database.

I've been looking into replica sets, but it looks like with that there always has to be a primary db, and that's the only one that has write privileges.

I would like both db's to be "primaries" - meaning they will both have read/write access, but I would also like them to auto-sync with each other every so often, so they both end up being clones of each other.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I guess I probably didn't word it clearly enough - obviously if these databases outright synced with each other, one would clearly overwrite the other.  I guess I would just like the dbs to "update" each other, and add any records that don't exist in the other.  No idea if this is even possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I understand your request, you've picked the wrong DB technology if you wanted that to be automatic. It's not clear what you're trying to do -- you could use sharding to distribute write/read load?